# Elasticsearch Vs MongoDB Aggregation - Development Comparison with Example

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm converting **MongoDB** Query to **Elasticsearch** in **NodeJS** platform. While developing I'm facing some difficulties with *grouping and filtering* data (getting nested objects like **hits.hits._source**) within Elasticsearch Query like we doing in MongoDB Query.

Example:-

```
UserModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            uId: req.body.uId, timestamp: { $gte: req.body.date, $lte: new Date() }
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$eId",
            location: {
                $push: {
                    time: "$timestamp", lat: "$lat"
                }
            },
            timestamp: {
                $push: "$timestamp"
            },
            testId: { $first: "$testId" },
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            eId: 1, location: 1, testId: 1, max: { $max: "$timestamp" }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$location", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $eq: ["$location.time", "$max"] },
                then: "$$DESCEND",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            eId: 1, latitude: "$location.lat", testId: 1
        }
    },
]).exec(function (err, result) {
    console.log(result)
});
```

What will be the equivalent query in Elasticsearch? 
I'm looking for solution with grouping, unwinding and projecting (MongoDB concepts to Elasticsearch) required data with minimal nested response. 
Thanks in Advance.

EDIT:-

Adding Elasticsearch Document:-

```
{
          "timestamp": "2019-10-08T:02:50:15.54Z",
          "status" : 1,
          "eId": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a407",
          "location": [
            2.000,
            34.5664111801
          ],
          "zId": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a4ef"
},
{
          "timestamp": "2019-10-09T:02:50:15.54Z",
          "status" : 1,
          "eId": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a408",
          "location": [
            2.100,
            35.5664111801
          ],
          "zId": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a4ef"
},
{
          "timestamp": "2019-10-09T:03:50:15.54Z",
          "status" : 1,
          "eId": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a407",
          "location": [
            4.100,
            35.5664111801
          ],
          "zId": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a4ef"
},
{
          "timestamp": "2019-10-09T:03:40:15.54Z",
          "status" : 1,
          "eId": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a407",
          "location": [
            2.100,
            35.5664111801
          ],
          "zId": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a4e1"
},
{
          "timestamp": "2019-10-10T:03:40:15.54Z",
          "status" : 1,
          "eId": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a407",
          "location": [
            3.100,
            35.5664111801
          ],
          "zId": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a4e1"
}
```

1. Match with status =1, and Group By eId
2. With that results, group by timestamp and get max timestamp value

Expected Result:-

```
[
        {
            "_id": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a407",
            "max": "2019-10-10T:03:40:15.54Z", // max timestamp
            "zId": [
                "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a4e1",
                "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a4ef"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a408",
            "max": "2019-10-09T:02:50:15.54Z",
            "zId": [
                "5d5d7ce0c89852e7bad4a4ef"
            ]
        }, // ...etc 

    ]
```

Comment: I do not know mongoDb enough to answer your question but if you can provide a set of document and the expected results, I can try to give you an answer.

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel Thanks. Will add document.

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel Data added. Could you pls help me?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the documents. Sadly, I do not know any way to retrieve only the documents having the max timestamp field value.

The following query will allow you to filter by `status` and group by `eId` then get the max timestamp value, but it will not return the documents having the max timestamp value.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "status": 1
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "eId_group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "eId"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "max_timestamp": {
                    "max": {
                        "field": "timestamp"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This second query use a [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation to retrieve the documents grouped by `eId`. The returned documents are sorted by decreasing timestamp value so the documents having the max timestamp will be firsts, but you may also get documents with different timestamps.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "status": 1
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "eId_group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "eId"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "max_timestamp": {
                    "max": {
                        "field": "timestamp"
                    }
                },
                "top_documents": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 20,
                        "sort": { "timestamp": "desc"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the following mapping for the index

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "eId": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "zId": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This query will be inside body: {} right? And also Im getting error as, [illegal_argument_exception] Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [employeeId] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index.Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead. 

Note:- added keyword with all fields. But still getting some errors.

Comment: Yes, you should use `keyword` type for the field on which you perform aggregation. If you are also searching this field, you can create a subfield using another type. What are the other errors ?

Comment: Your timestamp values are also not correctly formatted for ISO 8601 notation. You should remove the : after T or you may change the date parsing format. I have updated the answer with the mapping I used.